# URL(url).openStream() with Proxy

Tags: java, proxy

is it possible to add a Proxy to my URL().openStream()?

```
scanner = new Scanner(new URL(url).openStream());
```

my Proxy has user and password

Comment: This is likely to be faster to google. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

maybe you can start with this:

```
String proxyUser = "";
String proxyPassword = "";
String proxyAddress = "";
int proxyPort = 8080;
InetSocketAddress sa = new InetSocketAddress(proxyAddress, proxyPort);
Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, sa);
URLConnection conn = url.openConnection(proxy);
sun.misc.BASE64Encoder encoder = new sun.misc.BASE64Encoder();
String encodedUserPwd = encoder.encode((proxyUser + ":" + proxyPassword).getBytes());
conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", "UTF-8");
conn.setRequestProperty("Proxy-Authorization", "Basic " + encodedUserPwd);
```

Comment: Just one remark - it's not good to use `sun.misc.BASE64Encoder` (or any other sun.*). There is no Base64 encoder in public java API. :-/ You can use codec from http://commons.apache.org/.

Comment: @Michał Šrajer, agreed now is only `@depreciated`, and in Java8 will be removed